# Do I need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() if I have no triggers and MAXDOP = 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've inherited an SQL Server 2008 system which uses `@@IDENTITY` in several stored procedures. Everything I've read is that this should almost definitely be replaced by `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

However, the system is currently stable and functioning correctly and I'm a little concerned about going in and making a blanket change because "I read that it's better online".

I've verified that the database has no triggers (`sysobjects where type = 'tr'`) and that the max degree of parallelism for the server is set to 0. So my answer is, is there any danger in using `@@IDENTITY` in this scenario? Obviously, if either of those changes then we may have a problem, but if the current setup is safe then I can prioritise accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no danger if you can guarantee that things won't change in the future - that's the risk - down the road someone adds a trigger, perhaps after you have left the company and then problems crop up that will be very difficult to find if you don't know what you are looking for.

I have no way of guaging how big a risk that is for you - maybe at a minimum  you could/should leave some comments in the stored procedure where the @@Identity is used to serve as a warning to people that come along after you.

Personally, I'd bite the bullet and update my code if I could.

Comment: Agreed - will have to go in and fix things, but glad to know there's not an immediate issue.